# Is there a way to return cell data as a tooltip in Tabulator (v5.0.7)

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I want to start by saying that I am by no means an expert in JavaScript, so apologies in advance if I am missing something obvious.

Example:
I'm trying to create a custom tooltip for column A. Using the data from another cell as the parameter for the output of column A's tooltip.

`{title: "title", tooltip: function(cell) {return anotherfunction(cell)}...`

When passing 'cell' through as a parameter, it's possible to view the information in the rest of the row `console.log(cell._cell)` but from what I've discovered, there's no way of accessing the rest of the data.

This is a code pen of the issue that I'm having (i've commented out the `console.log(cell._cell.value)` in the example, as this will make the table fail to render. So, looking at the browsers console, it's possible to see the data that is returned from `console.log(cell._cell)`.

I've tried to use Tabulators `cell.getData()`, `cell.getRow()`, `cell.getColumn()` etc (and a load of others) but each results in an error.

Codepen
https://codepen.io/lukeorriss/pen/yLzMapg

If someone could please point me in the right direction for accessing the data in another row from a tooltip function, this would be great. Thank you all, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tabulator use 2 types of definitions for tooltip .

1. ColumnComponent (Header Cell)
2. Cell (Data Cell)

So You have to put a condition for your `formatTooltip` function

```js
function formatTooltip(cell) {
    // Need to open browser console log to view this.
    if (cell._cell) {
        let { name, email, address } = cell.getData();

        return `You are ${name}, your email is ${email} and address is ${address}`;
    } else if (cell.type === "ColumnComponent") {
        return cell.getField();
    }
}
```

See My [Codepen](https://codepen.io/doublehrajput/pen/VwMbjEW)

Comment: Hi Double H, thank you for this. It works flawlessly. I've accepted your solution as the answer.

Comment: Although this is a great workaround, I believe it is still a bug in v5.0.  You should be able to call `getData()` on the cell object to get the row data as it was in v4.9.3. Here is an example: https://codepen.io/izmirli/pen/wvrdQoP